# Rails can't find Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

So, I have the following code. I want to access `timespans_path`,
but I can't.

```
<% content_for :div_header do%>
  <h1> Welcome, <%= @l_user.name %> </h1>
<% end %>

<% content_for :div_sub_header do %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to "show entries", entries_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "show groups", groups_path %>
     <% if can? :read, Subgroup %>
        ,
        <%= link_to " subgroups", subgroups_path %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    <li><%= link_to "show users", users_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "show actioncodes", actioncodes_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "show timespans", timespans_path %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I always get these errors:

```
NameError in Application#welcome
Showing C:/xampp/htdocs/fluxcapacitor/app/views/application/welcome.html.erb where line #16 raised:
undefined local variable or method `timespans_path' for #<#<Class:0x58b8610>:0x58b7e18>
```

This is my `route.rb`:

```
Fluxcapacitor::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#welcome'

  get 'login' => 'application#login'
  post 'login' => 'application#process_login'

  post '' => 'application#process_login'

  post 'send_request_account_mail' => 'application#send_request_account_mail' 
  post 'send_forgot_password_mail' => 'application#send_forgot_password_mail' 

  get 'forgot_password' => 'application#forgot_password'
  get 'request_account' => 'application#request_account'

  get 'welcome' => 'application#welcome'
  get 'logout' => 'application#logout'

  if Rails.env.development?
    get 'display_mail' => 'application#display_mail'
  end

  resources :users

  get 'multiple_new' => 'users#multiple_new'
  post 'multiple_new' => 'users#multiple_new'
  post 'multiple_create' => 'users#multiple_create'

  get 'users/:id/:hash/cal' => 'users#cal'

  resources :actioncodes

  resources :entries

  resources :timespans

  resources :groups do
    member do
      get 'search_admin'
      post 'search_admin'
      post 'add_admin'
      get 'remove_admin'
      post 'remove_admin'
    end
  end

  resources :subgroups do
    member do
      get 'search_user'
      post 'search_user'
      post 'add_user'
      get 'remove_user'
      post 'remove_user'

      get 'remove_admin'
      post 'remove_admin'
    end
  end
end
```

Why am I getting the error? How can I fix it?

Comment: you should also put in the question about your `route.rb`

Comment: share your routes file as well

Comment: you have to add resources :timespans in your routes file, otherwise routes helper will not understand timespans_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
resources :timespans
```

in your route.rb

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't defined a path called `timespans`, so the view doesn't know what URL to render and is raising an error.

If you have a model called `Timespan` then adding `resources :timespans` to your routes file will create a path called `timespans_path` (among others), pointing to `/timespans`.

You can also create any arbitrary path called `timespans` path using the `:as` option, e.g.:

```
get "/the_url", to: "the_controller#the_action", as: :timespans
```

If you have problems with paths in the future, note that you can use the rake task `rake routes` to list all your generated routes and the names of their path helpers, which can be very helpful for debugging.